# Refactoring ifs

Tags: c#, refactoring

How do I refactor the below code which contains many ifs and each block contains different scenarios.

```
if(condition1)
{
  ConfigCondition1();
  GetSetCondition1Results();
}
if(condition2)
{
  ConfigCondition2();
  GetSetCondition2Results();
}
if(condition3)
{
  ConfigCondition3();
  GetSetCondition3Results();
}
```

Comment: Why refactor it?

I would probably use a switch statement

Comment: why do you want to refactor it and to which way? my answer now will be use cases (but that wont help a lot i suppose)

Comment: Polymorphism may be the answer, but we don't know what you are doing and what you are trying to achieve. What context is this code part of?

Comment: May be you can use Dictionary<condition,Action> type to store the conditions and based on the condition you can get the action delegate having those related methods already assigned and execute it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using the [Strategy Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

The strategy pattern encapsulates an algorithm in an object and helps you to refactor conditional statements to a simple function call.

[Here is a nice example in .NET](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternStrategy.aspx#_self1) that you can use.

Answer (score 2):

[Strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) seems best suited to your problem.

Using Strategy Pattern the client can choose which algorithm will be performed in runtime from a set of algorithms that were implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this guideline.

- Do all the `if` statement compare to same value? If yes, use `switch` block
- Does one `if` block exclude the others? If yes, use `else if`.
- Does one block depend on the value of another? If yes, nest them one inside another.
- If none of the above, i.e. all blocks must be checked regardless, no more optimization you can do.